# PowerShell: Send Email with Body as Variable

Tags: email, powershell, variables

I have a script that is supposed to check whether or not users match between two reports.  If any users match it should send one message.  If users do not match, I want it to send a message that just says "No users to move."  My issue is that no matter what I do, it always sends the same message.

```
$TermRep = Import-Csv TestFileTerm.csv
$Donna = Import-Csv TestFileDonna.csv

#Job to match users between CSVs
$Job = ForEach($i in $TermRep){
$TID = $($i.UserID)
ForEach($u in $Donna){
$DID = $($u.UserID)
If($TID -eq $DID){
"Move-ADObject -Identity $TID -TargetPath 'NEWPATH' `r`n"
            }
    }
}

$smtpServer = "server.stuff.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "PowerShell.Reports@work.com"
$msg.To.Add("me@work.com")
#$msg.To.Add("administrator2@test.com")
$msg.Priority = "High"
$msg.Subject = "Users To Move"
$msg.Body = "The following users exist in Termination Report and need to be moved.  Please run the following commands: `r`n $Job"
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

I've tried making the `$msg.body` into an

```
If($TID -eq $DID){
$msg.Body = "The following users exist in Termination Report and need to be moved.  Please run the following commands: `r`n $Job"}
Else{$msg.Body = "No users to move."}
```

It still only puts out the first option, regardless of whether or not the `If` is true.  I also tried adding directly under/outside the `ForEach`

```
If($TID -ne $DID){
$Job = "No users to move."
}
```

And if I run `$Job` its value is `"No users to move."` but it still runs the other line in the email.  Can anyone help?  PowerShell v2.0.  I tried putting `$Job = @()` in the `If` to clear it first too, but no change.

## Additional attempt

I've also tried formatting this way:

```
$msg.Body = "The following users exist in Termination Report and need to be moved.  Please run the following commands:`r`n"
If($Job -like "*"){
$msg.Body += "$Job"
}
Else{
$msg.Body = "No user to move for $Date."
}
```

If `$Job` has any value, I still get the correct results, but again, the `Else` statement doesn't work here.  I also tried `$msg.Body += "No user to move for $Date."` which also does not work.

## Solved it.

I changed that last one from a `-like` to a `-notlike` and that seems to have fixed it:

```
If($Job -notlike ""){
$msg.Body += "$Job"
}
Else{
$msg.Body += "No users to move for $Date."
}
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Comment: are you sure `$TID` and `$DID` match when you to the if check. Looking at your code once you get a match on a TID and DID it just keeps looping and `$TID` and `$DID` change again.

Comment: Also could you not just use compare-object for the initial comparison work?

Comment: @DaneBoulton not sure I understand.  I'm getting the results I want from the loop, and yes, they do keep looping through so I get a result for every line against every other line, but I wasn't really worried about it.

Comment: @Matt If you can show me the `Compare-Object` with proper syntax for this I'd be happy to try it.  I was having syntax trouble with it yesterday, so I switched to this.

Comment: Are you just looking for any matches between the two lists then?

Comment: Re: additional attempt: `"" -like "*"` returns $true

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks I just figured that out myself and updated my question to include my answer.

Comment: `If($Job){}` should have also sufficed as long as you initialize it as "" between passes.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen There you go knowing stuff about `-like` again.

Comment: @Matt Title on my CV says `professional -disliker`